# ClickOnce and extra files

Tags: c#, clickonce

I'm trying to convince my team that using ClickOnce will be good for us regarding deployment and updates. The only issue I have run across that isn't a seller is the fact that external files ( SqlCe data files, log files, etc ) can't be coded to exist in the same directory as the executable.

One workaround I suggested is that we always code to use a known directory on the c: drive but that just seems like a hack.

Is there a better way to use ClickOnce with external files or is this only way?

Comment: have you looked into using config files what you are saying and what you are wanting.. seem like two different things.. remember one thing.. all things are possible thru CODE...

Comment: Do you control the environment(s) where this app will be used?

Comment: Using the app.config file might be a good way to choose the path for files at runtime. I'll have to give that some consideration. Thanks :-)

Austin, what do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose which files to include in the deployment in the project properties > Publish tab > Application Files...

Is the issue that you have the external files in a folder in the project but want to deploy them to the same folder as the executable? It's simple at startup to get the executing assembly path and then the path to any subfolders your app requires.

ClickOnce is great but it has its annoyances. The one that's bitten me most recently is that it [doesn't update if it's pinned to a Windows 7 Taskbar](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/416615/clickonce-apps-dont-behave-as-expected-when-pinned-to-taskbar-in-windows-7).

Comment: Great article. I see that article is from 2009. Is that still an issue to this day? 

Some files are generated at runtime such as log files. Some are added by the user such as SqlCe data files. The issue I see using ClickOnce is that a user won't be able to find the location of the application to put a SqlCe data file or be able to find the log files if needed by customer support.

That's what led me to think that a location defined outside of the executable was the best/only way.

Comment: Example: currently, the logging ( we use Log4Net ) is configured to use a relative path for its rolling file appenders. This relative path will be extremely hard for a user to locate that log file from what I understand about ClickOnce.

Comment: Unfortunately the pinning issue still exists. Now that I understand your issue better, I would recommend putting those folders in the user local application data system folder. The root is Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData or CommonApplicationData -- you should create your app's folder in that.

Comment: Ah... I didn't think of those folders! Great suggestion. I'm going to research that avenue Thanks!